# xcode workspace multi Project "no such module" for a pods

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, xcode-project, xcode-workspace, xcodeproj

Hi here's basically my Podfile configuration

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'Project1' do
  use_frameworks!
  workspace 'MyWorkspace'
  project 'Project1.xcodeproj'

  pod 'RxSwift', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'Project2', :path => 'Project2'
  pod 'Project3', :path => 'Project3'


end

target 'Project2' do
  use_frameworks!
  workspace 'MyWorkspace'
  project 'Project2/Project2.xcodeproj'

  pod 'RxSwift', '~> 4.0'

end

target 'Project3' do
  use_frameworks!
  workspace 'MyWorkspace'
  project 'Project3/Project3.xcodeproj'

    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'RxAlamofire'
    pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 3.0.0'
    pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 5.0'

end
```

The problem is I have a **"no such module RxSwift"** from my Project2 files only when I build Project1 (which using Project2).

Everything else is working, project are recognized as local pods etc.

I tried to :

- update searPath of Project2 adding RxSwift adding "$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/RxSwift"
- adding RxSwift.framework directly in Linked Framework and Librairies
- Deintegrate pods, delete DerivedData celan build etc ...

But every time a build the entire workspace, I have this **"No such module RxSwift"** from a Project2 file.

Do you have an idea of anything else I can check / try, or something I did wrong ?

I'm using **Xcode 9.1** and **CocoaPod 1.3.1**

*PS : my workspace is composed of 5 project set as local pods dependencies, and I know that put every thing in one project would surely fix this but what a mess I'll have.*

Thanks !